# Trying to run 2 different versions of a project at the same time, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I recently deleted JQueryMobile.js from my project and am now trying to apply the classes so I that I can link the css. In order to do this I need a side by side comparison of the two projects(the other one having JQuery Mobile still). I copied the old project to a separate folder. I then opened them up in different instances of Visual Studio 2012. Problem is that only the one with JQuery Mobile ever works, and the programs use the same port. How can I fix this so that I can run the two different versions of the same project at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just give the projects different ports? Go to Properties of your project, Web tab and in Servers pick IIS Express making sure that both have different ports.

Comment: That was it, I feel foolish now. I'm used to the port changing automatically.

Comment: No worries mate, sometimes we miss the simplest things :)